# CM 8.5 XPM continually prompts for Update Preview when page is in bundle workflow

Tags: web8.5, experience-manager, workflow

We have a page with a single component on it, both part of a bundle with workflow associated. When user 1 changes the page metadata via XPM, they get an Update Preview prompt (which I assume is correct as XPM is detecting the metadata change) and event system code picks up on the page check-in and starts bundle workflow. The workflow notification appears - all good.

Now - if user 2 has the same page open in XPM at the same time as the above, they also get an Update Preview prompt (again, seemingly correct as the page metadata has changed). But when they click to update, the page reloads and the Update Preview prompt reoccurs. This happens continually no now matter how many times an update is done.

I noticed that the call to GetPreviewToken for user 2 is always returning no token - just {d:}

When user 1 finishes the activity only then will an Update Preview by user 2 then be successful, with GetPreviewToken returning a token and the prompt disappearing.

Is this behaviour correct - it "feels" like a bug, but I guess the Preview Web Serice is being prevented from fast track publishing the page because of the workflow lock?

Comment: This feels like a bug to me too. If Collaborative Workflow is in place (and all users can see minor versions), then I'd expect User 2 to be able to 'Update Preview' and see the (in Workflow) changes but not be able to edit the contents. If Collaborative Workflow isn't in play, then I'd expect XPM to compare the current version to the last major version.